# split string array c#

Tags: c#, string

So I have multiple arrays of strings. Within each array I have a string which uses '|' as a separator. What I need is to create a string with the first elements of the array up until the '|'.

So in the example I need 6485,6486,6487,6509,6510,6511,6533,6534,6535,|
[image]

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: Interesting problem. Good luck!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO isn't a write my code service.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.Split()` to split the original strings, then store the first ones in a separate array, then use `String.Join()` to concatenate them

```
string[] tempStrings = new string[stringArray.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++) 
{
    tempStrings[i] = stringArray[i].Split(@"|")[0];
}

string result = String.Join(",", tempStrings);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using System.Linq :

```
string[] temp = new string[] { "1,2,3|4,5,6|7,8,9", "10,11,12|13,14,15", "16,17,18"};
var result = String.Join(",", temp.Select(x => x.Split('|').FirstOrDefault())
                                   .ToList());
```

With null and empty values :

```
string[] temp = new string[] { "1,2,3|4,5,6|7,8,9", "10,11,12|13,14,15", "16,17,18", "", null };
var result = String.Join(",", temp.Select(x => x?.Split('|').FirstOrDefault())
                                   .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                                   .ToList());
```